# Angular 2 Service : return local variable or do a promise

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to make a call only once. If the call has already been done, I need to return the local variable.

The service :

```
public currentUser: User;

getUser() {
    if (this.currentUser) {
        return this.currentUser;
    }
    else {
        return this.http.get('/api/user/')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                this.currentUser = response.json() as User;
                return this.currentUser;
            });
    }
}
```

If the user is null, the call is done but not retrieved in the component since the call is asynchronous. How can I achieve that ?

I tried this in the component :

```
getUserFromService() {
    let serviceReturn = this.userService.getUser();

    if (serviceReturn instanceof User) {
        this.user = serviceReturn;
    }
    else {
        let promise = serviceReturn as Promise<User>;
        promise.then(
            response => {
                this.user = response;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

It is working the first time, but the second time, it does not recognise the serviceReturn as an user and go the `else`, which throw an error. And I think it's not a good way to do, it must be a better way.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting back a promise from `this.http.get`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the line in the question, just did an edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you'll get two different return types, `Promise<User>` and `User`. Then your consumer of your service will always have to make sure which one they are receiving. Best would be to always return a `Promise`:

```
private currentUser: Promise<User>;

getUser() {
    if (!this.currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = this.http
           .get('/api/user/')
           .map(r => r.json())
           .toPromise();
    } 
    return this.currentUser;
}
```

Now all a consumer has to do:

```
async doSomething(): Promise<any> {
    let user: User = await this.userService.getUser();
}
```

Just keep in mind if you add the `async` keyword in front of a method it will **always** return a `Promise`. This `Promise` contains whatever you are returning inside this method. If you don't want to use this you can always go about like this, but readability of your code decreases:

```
doSomething(): any {
    this.userService.getUser().then((user: User) => {

    });
 }
```

Comment: This should work to but I prefer the other answer with `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @Robouste the other answer has a little design flaw that if you call the method twice, and it hasn't returned the first time, it will do the same request to the server twice. My answer does not suffer such terrible consequences

Comment: I have notice that the user is loaded twice when two different components are calling the service on the same page, which is not conveniant. I'll try this solution then.

Comment: I tried this answer but my IDE (VSCode) does not recognize the word `await`. From where should I import it ?

Comment: You should update your `TypeScript` to at least 2.1. This is when `async/await` was introduced. You should also mark your method as `async`. I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm using TS 2.2.2 :) but yes, I found out that I needed the do this inside a function with async. The compiler error is not very smart.

Comment: Is the other answer still somewhere available?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the `async/await` stuff a bit, I think it might be also ok to use `async/await` inside the service and have currentUser as an actual `User` instead of a `Promise<User>`:

```
private currentUser: User;

async getUser() {
    if (!this.currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = await this.http
            .get('/api/user/')
            .map(r => r.json());
    } 
    return this.currentUser;
}
```

The method `getUser()` now always returns a `Promise<User>`
I think, the code is a bit better readable this way. The downside is obviously, that *inside* the service, you should probably use `getUser()` as well instead of `currentUser` directly.